# How can I see the results of an input node or any other updates of data with xquery?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to know how can I see the result of an update of data over an xml with xquery. You know, insert node...

I have this, for example (I'm using BaseX btw):

```
insert node
<dance id="7">
    <name>Foxtrot</name>
</dance>
before //Dances/dance[1]
```

This is not returning error, but I can't see the result in the file and anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an example XML like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Dances>
    <dance id="3">
        <name>Lambada</name>
    </dance>
    <dance id="7">
        <name>Foxtrot</name>
    </dance>
    <dance id="9">
        <name>Waltz</name>
    </dance>
</Dances>
```

You can insert new elements by reconstructing the sample XML with the following XQuery:

```
let $a      := for $x at $pos in doc("sample.xml")/Dances/dance return ($x)
let $insBef := 2
let $new    := <dance id='55'><name>Salsa</name></dance>
return
    <Dances>
        {insert-before($a,$insBef,$new)}
    </Dances>
```

This inserts the 'Salsa' node before the second node ($insBef = 2 = 'Foxtrot'). The result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dances>
    <dance id="3">
        <name>Lambada</name>
    </dance>
    <dance id="55">
        <name>Salsa</name>
    </dance>
    <dance id="7">
        <name>Foxtrot</name>
    </dance>
    <dance id="9">
        <name>Waltz</name>
    </dance>
</Dances>
```